# Send data from an Arduino to the Internet using Python

Tags: python, arduino

My wish is to make an Arduino card(which only have a usb cable) useful by sending his data to a web analytics solution such as Piwik by using Python.

So far, I discovered, that I needed to install pySerial in order to discuss with Arduino (no problem)
http://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-Python-and-Arduino-with-pySerial/

then I discovered how to print a Hello World from Arduino, no problem too.

Unfortunately I am stucked at the last step, which is how to grab the data from Arduino to send it to the Internet. As I don't know Python I don't know what should I do, here is my code:

```py
import serial, httplib
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
    data = arduino.readline()[:-2]
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("demo.piwik.org")
    conn.request("HEAD","/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1&action_name=")(data)
    res = conn.getresponse()
```

Any ideas how could the information (data) could be concatenate with `demo.piwik.org/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1&action_name=` ?
data is containing "Hello world" then I wish to have at the end:
`/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1&action_name=Hello world`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
conn.request("HEAD","/piwik.php?idsite=7&rec=1&action_name={}".format(data))
```

`{}` is a placeholder, whatever you pass in to format(.. will be added to your string

Comment: I think it would be better to use `.format(urllib.parse.quote(data))` (for python 3) or `.format(urllib.quote(data))` (for python 2)